# Getting operator sizeof to differentiate among simple address, pointer and array (possibly with a macro?)

Tags: c, pointers, macros, sizeof, preprocessor

I would like to pass as the second argument to function `mem` the "correct" size of its first argument, which is an address to void.

I thought of using a macro, `MEM`, which uses the operator `sizeof`. This macro is supposed to "infer" at pre-processing time the "correct" size by looking at the text, i.e. how the first argument is written in code.

Except my macro it does not work well when the argument is an array that is passed with the name of the array (`arr`). (Note that the macro works well if I pass `&arr`, as suggested in the comments)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MEM(addr) mem(addr,sizeof *addr) // <-- does not work for arrays

void mem(const void* , int );

int main()
{
    int t=3;;
    int arr[10];
    int* p=&t;

    MEM(&t); // --> mem(&t,sizeof *&t)   <- OK!
    MEM(p); // --> mem(p,sizeof *p   <- OK! 

    MEM(arr); // --> mem(arr,sizeof *arr)  <- NO! I WANT THE SIZE OF THE ALL ARRAY!
           // SO I WANT --> mem(arr,sizeof arr)
    return 0;
}

void mem(const void* pp, int bytestoread) // prints bytestoread bytes starting from address pp
{
    int i;
    unsigned char* p=(unsigned char*)pp;
    for(i=0;i<bytestoread;i++)
    {
        if(i%8==0)
        {
            if(i!=0) printf("\n");
            printf("%p: ",p);
        }
        printf("%02x ",*p);
        p++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

If there's a different solution or approach to my problem other then a macro, even better. But arrays decay when passed as parameters to a function, so I don't see how I can use a function to accomplish what I want.

I would be happy even if there was some hack with the C preprocessor, like using the stringizing preprocessor operator `#` on the name of the address written in code and selectively compile MEM accordingly, but I couldn't do that.   (maybe using also the `#if #else #endif` preprocessor directives ...? )

**FOLLOW-UP**:

The following would be a tentative solution that exploits the fact that for an array `arr` (as opposed to a regular pointer) `&arr`==`arr`...

```
#define SIZE(add) (  #add[0]=='&' ? 
                     sizeof *add : 
                     ((void*)add==(void*)&add ? sizeof add : sizeof *add)  )

#define MEM(address) mem( address, SIZE(address) )
```

...but of course this, as is, doesn't compile when `address` is written as `&t` in the code (where `t` is an `int` for example), because `&&t` is not syntactically correct, even if the check `#add[0]=='&'` makes sure it would never be executed.

1) Is there a way to make it work? 
2) Or should I write a parser that outputs the code I want to be compiled based on the text I pass to the parser?
3) Why is the C pre-processor so strict regarding what I can use as a condition in #if directives? (I cannot even use string literals nor # operator! Only const expressions like 2>1 or other defined macro are allowed)

Comment: One way would be to have a predefined value as the last element of the array. In the `mem` function, you could loop over the array until you find the last (predefined) element and thus you could get the length of the array.

Comment: Interesting idea, but in this case the function `mem` is supposed to be a utility function, that works on all kinds of variable addresses, pointers, arrays. So it shouldn't assume a special format as input, nor can it modify the memory.

Comment: Why not just specifiy the address of `arr` with `MEM`: `MEM(&arr);`? `&arr` is the same value as`&arr[0]` (to which `arr` decayed when being passed to a function). Those two addresses are of different type but `mem()` takes a `void`-pointer, so the type passed does not matter.

Comment: This smells a bit like an XY problem.  Why do you want this macro?  I expect that it would be error-prone, because anybody using it must already understand when its argument is actually an array not an array that decayed into a pointer.  At that point, IMO you should just use `sizeof` directly: it's clearer and more idiomatic.

Comment: @alk what you propose does indeed work! Thank you!  I just have to be careful not to use the name of the array as its address, but always its name prefixed by `&`. Same value, but different pointer types of course.  This simple precaution sidesteps the all issue. I'm still curious if there's a hack solution that makes clever use of the preprocessor to selectively compile two different macros, as it may come in handy in many other circumstances...

Comment: @jamesdlin I concede it's a hack, but I'm just curious if there is a hack/solution in terms of the preprocessor, as it may be useful in many other cases.

Comment: The main concern I have is that the whole approach does *not* work (with no chance to make it work) for dynamically allocated memory, like `char * string42 = malloc(42 + 1);`.

Comment: @alk well, but that's expected: after all you can only create an array on the stack. On the heap (with `malloc`) you just allocate contiguous space, whose address is returned as a pointer. So ultimately in main you're dealing with a pointer, not with an array.  Do I miss something? Thank you as always

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no obvious solution with `MEM` macro, although there might be a solution with preprocessor condition expressions where according to the type of the operand we decide how to calculate the size.

The common practice in C is creating functions with an extra argument that takes the size of the data container. So you would write something like this, without macro usage at all:

```
int t = 3;
int arr[10] = {0};
int *p = &t;

mem(&t, sizeof(t)); 
mem(p, sizeof(*p));
mem(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])); // <- 40/4 = 10
```

This is quite verbose but in this case, you could rely on this and be sure that you're getting the expected behavior.

Comment: Sure, you can provide the second argument to `mem` manually. That's the way I currently use `mem`.  But I was curious if there was a way to "automate" that.  If only there was a clever hack with `#if` `#else` preprocessor directives to selectively compile two versions of `MEM`...